# Can CS2J convert 1000+ lines of code?

Tags: java, c#

Have someone of you got any experiences with [Convertor CS2J](http://www.cs2j.com/)?

If yes, can it convert 1000 lines code without any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, but be aware that the tool isn 't updated for 4 years and a lot of .NET calls will not be converted.
However you can extend the existing Netframework translation files to target more of the .NET framework.